# ConstraintLayout include positioning issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-include

Portion of an activity layout included from external layout definition. After including some UI elements lose their original positioning.

Original layout has text positioned to the left:

[image]

Included layout centers the same text:

[image]

Text elements are defined as:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/terms_of_service"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="48dp"
            android:minHeight="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView46"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Display Terms of Service"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see, **app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"** positions text to the left.

In the activity layout its included with necessary constraints:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/legal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include__ad"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Layout Inspector confirms that **textView46** in resulting layout does not have **app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"** attribute - this positions text at the centre.

What do I need to do to retain the positioning in included layout?

Comment: What happens when you don’t wrap it in ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 0):

The *ConstraintLayout* in the included layout is inheriting the `*:layout_*` attributes from the include tag. In essences, what you see is

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/terms_of_service"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:maxHeight="48dp"
        android:minHeight="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView46"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Display Terms of Service"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Because the inner _ConstraintLayout has a width of `wrap_content` and is constrained to the parent start/end, it is centered in the outer layout.

Remove the end constraint on the include tag and it should work.

To do this delete the end constraint for the include statement: Delete `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`. You can also just add `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.00"` and leave the end constraint.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please clarify what do you mean by 'end constraint on the include tag'?

Comment: None of suggested helps, unfortunately. Using the Layout Inspector I found that textView46 does not have app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" after inclusion - this positions it center in the container.